# Single Sign On with CAS server in JAVA

Tags: java, single-sign-on, cas

I am new to java application development. I have to implement Single Sign on with CAS Server. I downloaded CAS Server and tried to run as steps in this tutorial.

http://vamsichaithanya.blogspot.in/2013/01/cascentral-authentication-service.html

But when i use the command `mvn package install`, I am getting this error as

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install-file (default-cli) on project cas-server-webapp: Error installing artifact 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar': Failed to install artifact mysql:mysql-connector-java:jar:5.1.27-bin: /Users/test/Desktop/cas-server-3.5.1/cas-server-webapp (Is a directory) -> [Help 1]
```

Tests in error:

```
  testAfterPropertiesSet(org.jasig.cas.util.AutowiringSchedulerFactoryBeanTests): Error creating bean with name 'jobDetailTicketRegistryCleaner' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.SetUtils.orderedSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;
  testWiring(org.jasig.cas.WiringTests): Error creating bean with name 'serviceRegistryReloaderJobDetail' defined in file [/Users/sriseshaa/Desktop/cas-server-3.5.1/cas-server-webapp/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-configuration/applicationContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.collections.SetUtils.orderedSet(Ljava/util/Set;)Ljava/util/Set;
```

Please, suggest any good tutorials for this issue or any samples.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: New to Java Application development and you need to implement SSO? Good luck...

Comment: kayaman @: suggest any tutorials

Answer (score 2):

You can use [this demo](https://github.com/leleuj/cas-overlay-3.5.x) to test the CAS server 3.5.x or [this other demo](https://github.com/leleuj/cas-overlay-demo) to test the future CAS server 4.0.

Answer (score 0):

look at the below link, search **Create the pom.xml** you could see how add cas-server-webapp as a dependency

[cas maven overlay](https://wiki.jasig.org/display/CASUM/Best+Practice+-+Setting+Up+CAS+Locally+using+the+Maven+WAR+Overlay+Method)